# How to rename many variables with string suffixes

Tags: foreach, stata, stata-macros

In Stata, I have a set of variables that all begin with `pkg`.  In their current state, their endings are numeric: `pkg1`, `pkg2`, `pkg3`, `pkg4` and so on.

I need to change all of these variables' endings to strings: `pkgmz`, `pkggmz`, `pkgsp`, `pkgsptc` etc.

I have a column of these string endings, which I can designate as a local list.

For example:

```
local croplist mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric
```

How do I change the numeric endings to the string endings?

My guess at the code can be found below and the `???` indicate where I am stumped:

```
local croplist crops mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric

foreach x of varlist pkg* {
    local new1 = substr(`x', 1, 3)
    local new2 = ???
    rename `x' ``new1'`new2''
    label var ``new1'`new2'' "Avg district level `new2' price"
}
```

I wonder if it would be better to utilize the `regexr()` command, but can't think of a way to include it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need here to invoke regular expressions. You have the new suffixes; the prefix `pkg` is always the same, so the labour of extracting it repeatedly is unnecessary. The heart of the problem is cycling over two lists at once. Here is one way to fix your code.

```
local croplist mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric
local j = 1 
foreach x of varlist pkg* {
    local sffx : word `j' of `croplist' 
    rename `x' pkg`sffx'
    label var pkg`sffx' "Avg district level `sffx' price"
    local ++j 
}
```

Note also `rename` in Stata 12+ can handle this; `regexr()` is a function, not a command; a more general discussion in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0009 (a little out-of-date, but relevant on the main issue); you have too many quotation marks on your `rename` command, so it wouldn't work.

EDIT 30 July 2018

I tend now more often to use `gettoken`:

```
local croplist mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric
foreach x of varlist pkg* {
    gettoken sffx croplist: croplist
    rename `x' pkg`sffx'
    label var pkg`sffx' "Avg district level `sffx' price"
}
```

The local macro `croplist` is a stack. Each time around the loop we take the top item from the stack and leave the rest for the next time. 
Each time around the loop

Comment: Oh so that's how you advance the counter in stata!  Thanks!  I was always trying to do something like j=j+1, as you would do in most other programming (visual basic, matlab, etc.).  It seems to me stata goes out of its way sometimes to be different from intuitive programming conventions.

Comment: @Nick Cox You mentioned that the `rename` command in Stata 12+ can handle this. Is it possible to do so in a single `rename` command? I posted an answer with a few options using the new command, but I couldn't figure out if it was possible to use a single call.

Comment: @Michael A It is possible to do it with one command, but the only answer that occurs to me is not engaging. `rename (pkg1-pkg9 ) (pkgmz pkggmz pkgsp pkgsptc pkgmil pkgcof pkgsuk pkgtea pkgric)` Still, it remains true that people will spend minutes trying to think up a clever trick when the names could have been typed in seconds.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to do it. `tokenize` puts separate words in macros numbered 1 up. The nested reference ``` ``j'' ``` is handled just in elementary algebra: evaluate the inside macro reference first.

```
 
tokenize "mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric" 
forval j = 1/9 {
    rename pkg`j' pkg``j''
    label var pkg``j'' "Avg district level ``j'' price"
}
```

Comment: This would be good when the numbers are consecutive.  As it turns out in my case the numbers are not consecutive (although I thought they were when originally posted my question).  So I will give the check to Nick's first answer.  But both are very useful.

Answer (score 7):

Ben asked in a comment about incrementing counters held in local macros.

Stata's local macros are in general for holding strings; string
characters can be numeric, so holding numbers is a special case, but
naturally a very useful one. This thread alone has shown several
examples. It helps to hold that history in mind. A longstanding syntax
is based on the forms

```
local macname <contents>
```

and

```
local macname = <expression>
```

The first form copies  to `macname` while the second form
evaluates  before assigning the results to `macname`. The
main way to increment counters was for several versions

```
local j = `j' + 1
```

but the syntax

```
local ++j
```

is now allowed. However, although allowed

```
local j++
```

won't work as you may expect, although what happens is consistent with
the first syntax for macros.

So, if this looks a little odd given your background, that's
understandable, but local macros were intended for string processing,
not arithmetic. Mata is much more mainstream-like in this regard.

I wrote a tutorial on loops and macros in

Cox, N.J. 2002. How to face lists with fortitude. *Stata Journal* 2(2):
202-222

which is accessible to all at

http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0005

Answer (score 1):

As of Stata 12+, `rename` can handle this case in several ways.

This method creates a new macro `new_croplist` containing variable names `pkgmz pkggmz pkgsp pkgsptc pkgmil pkgcof pkgsuk pkgtea pkgric`, then uses `rename` to rename variables following the pattern `pkg<digits>` to the names specified in `new_croplist`. The numbers following `pkg` do not need to be consecutive.

```
local croplist mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric
local new_croplist
foreach name of local croplist {
    local new_croplist `new_croplist' pkg`name'
}
rename pkg# (`new_croplist')
```

A second method uses the new `rename` function twice; as before, this does not require consecutive numbers in the original names. The first command renames variables of the pattern `pkg<digits>` to the names specified in `croplist`. The second command adds the prefix `pkg` to the new variable names.

```
rename pkg# (`croplist')
rename (`croplist') pkg=
```

In both cases, and in general when using the `rename` command (referred to as `rename group` in Stata's documentation), the number of old variable names must match the number of new variable names, so make sure that the number of variables matched by `pkg#` matches the number of new names specified in `croplist'.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a counter as in @Nick's excellent example, is to employ
`macro shift`:

```
clear

forvalues i = 1 / 9 {
    generate pkg`i' = runiform()
}

local croplist mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric
tokenize "`croplist'"

foreach var of varlist pkg* {
    rename `var' pkg`1'
    label var pkg`1' "Avg district level `1' price"
    macro shift
}
```

You can also use the `ds` command to obtain a list of variable names starting with `pkg`:

```
local croplist mz gmz sp sptc mil cof suk tea ric
tokenize "`croplist'"

ds pkg*

foreach var of varlist `r(varlist)' {
    rename `var' pkg`1'
    label var pkg`1' "Avg district level `1' price"
    macro shift
}
```

In both cases you get:

```
pkgmz           float   %9.0g                 Avg district level mz price
pkggmz          float   %9.0g                 Avg district level gmz price
pkgsp           float   %9.0g                 Avg district level sp price
pkgsptc         float   %9.0g                 Avg district level sptc price
pkgmil          float   %9.0g                 Avg district level mil price
pkgcof          float   %9.0g                 Avg district level cof price
pkgsuk          float   %9.0g                 Avg district level suk price
pkgtea          float   %9.0g                 Avg district level tea price
pkgric          float   %9.0g                 Avg district level ric price
```